# How to update two column value vice versa using one UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server

I just got this question from my friend.
I have one table as given below

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(30),
SURNAME VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO @table(NAME, SURNAME)
VALUES('Mohit', 'Vaghadiya'),
      ('Paresh', 'Panchal'),
      ('Devid','Pietersen'),
      ('kapil','Soni')

===================================
| ID  |     NAME    |   SURNAME   |    
=================================
| 1   |   Mohit     |   Vaghadiya |
| 2   |   Paresh    |   Panchal   |
| 3   |   Devid     |   Pietersen |
| 4   |   kapil     |   Soni      |
===================================
```

I just want to update **NAME** column value of **ID** '1' with **SURNAME** of **ID** '3' and vice versa I want to update **SURNAME** column value of **ID** '3' with the **NAME** of **ID** '1'

output will be

```
===================================
| ID  |     NAME    |   SURNAME   |    
===================================
| 1   |   Pietersen |   Vaghadiya |
| 2   |   Paresh    |   Panchal   |
| 3   |   Devid     |   Mohit     |
| 4   |   kapil     |   Soni      |
===================================
```

I know we can do it like this

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(30)

SELECT @name = SURNAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 3

UPDATE @table
SET SURNAME = (SELECT NAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 1)
WHERE ID = 3

UPDATE @table
SET NAME = @name
WHERE ID = 1
```

But is there any possible way to do it by executing only one **UPDATE** statement?

Comment: So.... mysql or t-sql (since you tagged mysql and sql-server)?

Comment: @Aquillo This looks more like SQL Server.

Comment: @Aquillo ya, My example is given in sql-server but my question is still for both sql-server and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expressions, one for the name, other for the surname:

```
UPDATE @table
  SET name =
       case
         when ID = 1 then (SELECT SURNAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 3)
         else name
       end,

     surname =
       case
         when ID = 3 then (SELECT NAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 1)
         else surname
       end
WHERE ID in (1, 3)
```

**[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/463e6/3)**

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(30)

SELECT @name = SURNAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 3

UPDATE @table
SET SURNAME = CASE 
        WHEN ID = 3
            THEN (SELECT NAME FROM @table WHERE ID = 1)
        ELSE SURNAME
        END
    ,NAME = CASE 
        WHEN ID = 1
            THEN @name
        ELSE NAME
        END
WHERE id IN (1,3)
```

Just use a `CASE` statement to handle these two situations and update the `SURNAME` column first and then the `NAME` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table against itself with a condition that matches row 1 in the first set of the table with row 3 in the other. You can use the fact that `x+y-x = y` and `x+y-y = x`, i.e. the expression `(3+1) - ID` calculates the other ID, which gives `t1.ID = 4 - t2.ID`.

Then you need a condition on the values that you update, so that you only change the right one in each record:

```
update t1
set
  NAME = case t1.ID when 1 then t2.SURNAME else t1.NAME end,
  SURNAME = case t1.ID when 3 then t2.NAME else t1.SURNAME end
from
  MyTable t1
  inner join MyTable t2 on t2.ID = 4 - t1.ID
where
  t1.ID in (1,3)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83257/11

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE @table
SET    SURNAME = CASE
                   WHEN ID = 3 THEN (SELECT NAME
                                     FROM   @table
                                     WHERE  ID = 1)
                   ELSE SURNAME
                 END,
       NAME = CASE
                WHEN ID = 1 THEN (SELECT SURNAME
                                  FROM   @table
                                  WHERE  ID = 3)
                ELSE NAME
              END
WHERE  id IN ( 1, 3 )
```